# Задача Паскаль не могу прийти к иному(верному решению)

Tags: pascal

*Решал, решал и "дорешался"...*(целый день занимался решением задач)

**Чтобы ввести в курс дела - Собственно сама задача:**

> Даны числа от 1 до N. Вычислять: S=1/1+1/2+1/3 ..... + 1/N, вплоть до слагаемого, меньшего заданного E(E<1).

**Моё решение:**(*Часто приводит к ошибкам в процессе исполнения программы и я скорее прихожу к выводу что я неправильно понял задачу*)

```
program page42number4;

label met;
var
    N, k: integer;
    E, t: real;

begin
    Writeln('Write N - integer');
    Readln(N);
    met: Writeln('Write E - real (E<1)');
    Readln(E);
    if (E > 1) and (E <> 1) then goto met;
    k := 2;t := 0;
    while (k < N) do 
    begin
        if t < E then
        begin
            t := 1 / k + t;
            k := k + 2;
        end;
    end;
    Writeln('T=', t,'', 'E=', e);
end.
```

**P.S.Прошу помочь мне разобраться в своих ошибках.**

*Кстати по составленной мною блок-схеме все правильно должно быть, хотя опять же не факт что блок-схему верно составил*

Comment: Не-не, вы ж сами пишете, что `N` не определено заранее, а берётся из условия, что последнее слагаемое меньше `E`.

Comment: `log(n) + постоянная Эйлера-Маскерони` дает неплохую асимптотику для этого ряда.

Comment: Я в универе на лабах по asm для avr через функции программки писал, а вы в паскале через метки делаете. Не хорошо это. Специально для вашего случая существуют циклы `do...while` (или `repeat ...until`, уже не помню что в паскале есть)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки:

- Почему `k` увеличивается на 2, а не на 1?
- Почему `t` сравнивается с погрешностью `E`, а не `1/k`?
- Почему вы начинаете с k=2? Нужно с k=1.
- Почему вы сравниваете `k` и `N как условие выхода? Нужно`1/k`и`E`

В остальном всё нормально.

```
program page42number4;

label met;
var
    N, k: integer;
    E, t: real;

begin
    {
     N нас не интересует, потому что ограничения по N нет
     Writeln('Write N - integer');
     Readln(N);
    }
    met: Writeln('Write E - real (E<1)');
    Readln(E);
    if (E > 1) and (E <> 1) then goto met;

    { k должно быть равно 1, а не 2 на первой итерации }
    k := 1;t := 0;

    { условие выхода: 1/k < E => следовательно, пока 1/k >= E, продолжаем }
    while (1/k >= E) do 
    begin
        { if уже не нужен
        if t < E then
        begin }

            t := 1 / k + t;
            k := k + 1; { k увеличиваем на 1, а не на 2 }

        { end; }
    end;
    Writeln('T=', t,'', 'E=', e);
end.
```

Comment: **Спасибо**, _k=2 и увеличивается на 2 - это я уже пытался упростить, чтобы проверить ручками(бесконечные дроби - как-то не очень считаются)._

**Почему вы сравниваете k и N как условие выхода? Нужно 1/k и E`**
**Действительно, ещё раз огромное спасибо))**

Answer (score 0):

**В общем после не-которых рассуждений я пришел к данному и на мой взгляд верному решению:**

```
program page42number4;

label met;
var
    k: integer;
    E, t: real;

begin
    met: Writeln('Write E - real (E<1)');
    Readln(E);
    if (E > 1) and (E <> 1) then goto met;
    k := 1; t := 1;
    while (1/k > E) do 
    begin
        k := k + 1;
        t := 1 / k + t;
        end;
    Writeln('T=', t, ' ', 'E=', e);
end.
```

**P.S. Если вы считаете моё решение не верным просьба прокомментировать почему и как правильно.**

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, использование меток считается плохим тоном, вот вариант без меток с  циклом repeat-until:

```
program page42number4;

var
    k: integer;
    E, t: real;

begin
    repeat
    Begin
        Writeln('Write E - real (E<1)');
        Readln(E);
    End;
    until E<1;
    k := 1; t := 1;
    while (1/k > E) do 
    begin
        k := k + 1;
        t := 1 / k + t;
    end;
    Writeln('T=', t, ' ', 'E=', e);
end.
```

Comment: объясните пожалуйста почему использование меток считается плохим тоном?

Comment: @Aiswe потому, что код с метками очень плохо читается. Не зря в современных языках программирования от них отказались. Это пережитки Бейсика. Так уже давно никто программы не пишет.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу исправленного решения.

1. Если E<1, то условие E<>1 лишнее.
2. При вычислениях с плавающей точкой сумму лучше брать в обратном порядке (от K=1/E до 1), чтобы не накапливалась погрешность при больших N.

Судите сами. Результат имеет порядок O(ln N) - пусть O(1). При N=1 000 000  к этому числу должна добавиться величина на 6 десятичных порядков меньшая. Суммирование требует выравнивания данных по разрядной сетке, при это новое слагаемое будет сдвинуто на 6 десятичных (т.е. на 20 двоичных разрядов вправо), что повлечёт соответствующую ошибку округления за счёт обрезания информативных разрядов. Заметим, что указанная ситуация повторится практически миллион раз, что усугубит ситуацию с ошибкой ещё на три порядка.
При суммировании в обратном порядке ситуация проще, как минимум, на те же 20 двоичных разрядов.